# Oracle APEX Font APEX Issue with IE

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

We just upgraded to APEX 19.2 from 5.14.  The applications seemed to migrate fine in general but I have noticed an issue with applications in IE 11.  The font apex icons are not displaying.  I have regions with a refresh icon and they do not display.  The button operates fine but it's just an empty square.  Has anyone else encountered this or know of a solution?  This is mainly on my home page.  If I navigate away to another page in the application they are also missing from that page.  But when I navigate back they show up.  Everything is fine in Chrome but not IE.  I have to have this work in both.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: IE11 is already deprecated, I suggest you to not use IE

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you should be recommending that your users use a more modern browser such as Edge, Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.  Even if you do manage to find a workaround for your icon issue, Oracle has stated that they will be [dropping support for IE 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/htmrn/index.html#HTMRN-GUID-27133487-6647-4771-8EFF-8D283BB7AB31) in APEX 20.2.

Comment: We cannot "recommend" that.  IE11 is the current corporate standard.  Users do have Chrome and/of Firefox installed but we cannot develop for a single platform.  All developed and published applications and sites must operate on ALL corporate browsers.  IE 11 is on the schedule to be retired at some point.   My original issue is resolved however.  We had to disable pragma no-cache at the OHS server and it started working.